# latex summation notation getting compressed

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fractions

I have this code in latex

```
\begin{equation}
   \hat{k}=\dfrac{1}{\Delta t}\ln{\left(\dfrac{n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_t^2-
   \left(\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_t\right)^2}{n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_{t+\Delta t}r_t - 
    n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_tn\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_{t+\Delta t}}  \right)}
\end{equation}
```

but the summation notations are getting compressed as if like inline comments.
What could be the plausible problem? These are the related packages that I use.

```
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amsfonts,bm,amssymb,amsthm,parskip,eurosym,mathptmx,avant}
```

Answer (score 5):

You wrote,

> ... the summation [symbols] are getting compressed as if like inline [math]. What could be the plausible problem?

The issue, such as it is, is that if `\frac` occurs in display-math style, the numerator and denominator terms are typeset in text-style math -- with visually less prominent summation symbols.

If you wish to force both the numerator and denominator terms to be typeset in display-math style, I recommend using the following macro, called `\ddfrac` (short for "double display-style frac", I suppose:

```
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
```

The following screenshot shows both the original formula, which uses `\dfrac`, and the formula that employs `\ddfrac` and uses two extra pairs of parentheses in the denominator:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm,
            avant,mathptmx,mathrsfs,
            parskip,eurosym}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\hat{k}
&=\dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \ln{\left(
\dfrac{n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_t^{\!\!2}
   -\left(\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_t\right)^2}{n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_{t+\Delta t}r_t 
   -n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_tn\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_{t+\Delta t}} \right)}\\[2ex]
&=\dfrac{1}{\Delta t} 
\ln\left(
\ddfrac{n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_t^2
       -\biggl(\,\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_t\biggr)^2}{%
       n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_{t+\Delta t}r_t
       -\biggl(n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_t\biggr)
        \biggl(n\sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t}r_{t+\Delta t}\biggr)} 
\right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Latex/Tex supports different typographical styles in math-mode. You can switch between four modes:

- displaystyle
- textstyle
- scriptstyle and
- scriptscriptstyle

The nominator and denominator of fractions are typeset in textstyle mode by default. To switch to a specific mode you have to invoke one of the four commands: `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`

The best way to get a feeling for the different modes is to play around with them.

The following image illustrates the style of the different modes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\mytext[2][black]{%
    \color{#1}\text{\texttt{\textbackslash #2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\def\nominator{%
    n \sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t} r_t^2 
    - \left( \sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t} r_t \right)^2
}
\def\denominator{
    n \sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t} r_{t+\Delta t} r_t 
    - n \sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t} r_t n \sum_{t=0}^{n-\Delta t} r_{t+\Delta t}
}

\setlength\jot{2em}

\begin{align*}
    \hat{k} 
        & = & \frac{\mytext[green!60!black]{displaystyle}}%
               {\mytext[blue!70!black]{textstyle}}
        & = \dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \ln{%
            \left(
                \frac{% 
                    % Switch to displaystyle
                    \displaystyle\color{green!60!black}\nominator
                }{%
                    % Switch to textstyle
                    \textstyle\color{blue!70!black}\denominator
                }  
            \right)
        } \\
        & = & \frac{\mytext[orange!90!black]{scriptstyle}}%
               {\mytext[red]{scriptscriptstyle}}
        &= \dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \ln{%
            \left(
                \frac{% 
                    % Switch to scriptstyle
                    \scriptstyle\color{orange!90!black}\nominator
                }{%
                    % Switch to scriptscriptstyle
                    \scriptscriptstyle\color{red}\denominator
                }  
            \right)
        }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```